# No puedo llenar un simple array Java

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Algo simple y sencillo.

```
switch(menu_ini)
                {
                    case 1: // Ingresar datos!.


                        int i;

                        for (i = 1; i == item.length; i++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("ITEM?:");
                            item[i] = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Categoria?:");
                            categoria[i] = sc.next();


                        }

                        System.out.println("DUNNO");



                    break;
```

El switch funciona de maravilla, pero al entrar en el case 1, deberia mostrarme el mensaje "ITEM?" para luego dejarme ingresar el String...despues el mensaje "CATEGORIA?" para luego dejarme ingresar otro String...
Y asi ir llenando el array.
Sin embargo, eso no ocurre..se salta completamente el bucle FOR e imprime la cadena "DUNNO" que puse mas abajo para testear que efectivamente ingrese al case 1.

Ya probé con sc.nextLine() y pasa lo mismo...
¿Que estoy haciendo mal?. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ese for no tiene sentido de usar == pues nunca va a iterar sobre los valores y esa es precisamente la idea de un bucle como el for

Comment: Gracias, lo termine resolviendo!